# How do we prove to say the value of trigonometric angles

Tags: trigonometry

We say $ cos 0 ^ 0$ = 1 and sin 0 degree = 0. Why it it like that ? What is the proof for it?

I’m not able to get it. I thought of using the formula x=r$\theta$. But not understand what to put.[image]

If cos 0 degree = 1 is value of x , then x = 1 * 0 should be 0.

Comment: In the picture, $x$ denotes the arc length and $X$ is the coordinate along the horizontal axis. I think that this choice of $x$ as arc length is very weird and confusing. So anyway, to your question: Let's consider the case of a zero angle. The arc length has nothing to do with the trigonometric functions. But rather, the coordinate of the rotated point (on the unit circle) tells us the values of the trigonometric functions. At a zero angle, the coordinates are $(1,0)$. That tells us that $\cos{0}=1$ (the first coordinate) and $\sin 0 = 0$ (the second coordinate). That's the end of the story.

Comment: The definition of $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$ is the following: If you take a rectangular triangle $ABC$, with hypotenuse $AB$ of length 1 and angle $\widehat{BAC}=\alpha$, then $\cos\alpha$ is the length of ${AC}$, while $\sin\alpha$ is the length of $BC$. Now, what happen if $\alpha=0$? Then triangle collapses, that is $AB=AC$ (so $\cos\alpha=\mbox{length}AB=1$) and $B=C$, so $BC$ became a single point (so $\sin\alpha=\mbox{length}BC=0$)

Comment: Do you mean this? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40364/what-reasoning-is-behind-the-names-of-the-trigonometric-functions-sine-secan (checked answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I got it.